# Rename subdirectory with value extracted from XML (Python)

Tags: python, xml, extract

I'm need to do the following:

1. I have directory - "/home/vaer/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/XML/FILES"
2. In it I have subdirectories - 111,24344,542123
3. In these subdirectories I have other subdirectories - 1,2,3
4. In these subdirectories there are .xml files 'info.xml' which contains information I need to use for renaming the subdirectories - 1,2,3...

For exampes, in subdirectory 1, there is a info.xml which contains value 1422 (this is the last attribute in one of the tags). The new name of the subdirectory should be 1422.

This is what I've done so far, but it's not working. Any ideas what can I change:

```
import path
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import os

path = r"/home/vaer/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/XML/FILES"

with os.scandir(path) as dirs:
    for entry in dirs:
        for x in entry:
            if x == 'info.xml':
                tree_xml = ET.parse(x)
                root_xml = tree_xml.getroot()
                new_dir_value = ((root_xml[0].text).split('/'))[-1]
                os.rename(entry,new_dir_value)
```

I get the following error:

```
/home/vaer/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/XML/venv/bin/python /home/varum/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/XML/main.py Traceback (most recent call last): File "/home/varum/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/XML/main.py", line 9, in <module> 
for x in entry: TypeError: '
posix.DirEntry' object is not iterable 
Process finished with exit code 1
```

The path towards the 'info.xml' is like this one:

/home/vaer/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/XML/FILES/111/1/info.xml

/home/vaer/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/XML/FILES/111/2/info.xml

I tried with os.walk method, but I get only the value from the first .XML and d are not the 1,2,3 subdirectories, but 111,24344,542123 sudirecoties:

```
> for root, dirs, files in
> os.walk(r"/home/vaer/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/XML/FILES",
> topdown=True):
>     for r in root:
>         for d in dirs:
>             for f in files:
>                 if f == 'test.xml':
>                     new_values = []
>                     tree_xml = ET.parse(f)
>                     root_xml = tree_xml.getroot()
>                     new_dir_value = ((root_xml[0].text).split('/'))[-1]
>                     new_values.append(new_dir_value)
>                     print(new_values,d)
```

Thank you for the ideas!

Comment: add print of `new_dir_value` and `entry` before you call rename. Does it help?

Comment: I receive the following error:

"for x in entry:
TypeError: 'posix.DirEntry' object is not iterable"

I don't know what can I do.

Comment: please share the full stack trace

Comment: ```
"/home/vaer/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/XML/venv/bin/python /home/varum/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/XML/main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/varum/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/XML/main.py", line 9, in <module>
    for x in entry:
TypeError: 'posix.DirEntry' object is not iterable

Process finished with exit code 1
```

This is the whole error message.

The path towards the 'info.xml' is like this one:

/home/vaer/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/XML/FILES/111/1/info.xml
/home/vaer/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/XML/FILES/111/2/info.xml
...

Comment: I think that `for x in entry` is where the error is thrown.

Comment: Yes, I think there is the problem, but I don't get why and how I can fix it.

Comment: look at `os.walk` https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/os_walk.htm

Comment: Done. I have edited it. :)